# About Extended Goldbach's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Hello,

This question is a follow-up from [About Goldbach's conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture).

As $N_{2}(n)=\sum_{r\leq n}1_{\mathbb{P}}(n-r)1_{\mathbb{P}}(n+r)$, Chebotarev's theorem allows to write:

$$\dfrac{N_{2}(n)}{\pi(n)}\sim \dfrac{N_{1}(n)}{\varphi(P_{ord_C(n)})}$$

So that

$$N_2(n)\sim \pi(n) \dfrac{N_{1}(n)}{\prod_{2\lt p\le \sqrt{2n-3}}(p-1)}$$.

One can easily show that $$N_{1}(n)={\prod_{2\lt p\le \sqrt{2n-3}}(p-2)}\prod_{p\vert n \\ p>2}\dfrac{p-1}{p-2}$$.

Thus one gets

$$N_{2}(n)\sim \pi(n)\dfrac{C}{\log\sqrt{2n-3}}\prod_{p\vert n \\ p>2}\dfrac{p-1}{p-2}$$ and, through the prime number theorem:

$$N_{2}(n)\sim \dfrac{Kn}{\log^{2} n}\prod_{p\vert n \\ p>2}\dfrac{p-1}{p-2}$$ with $K>0$.

As $N_{2}(n)$ is the number $G(2n)$ of couples $(p,q)$ such that $p+q=2n$, $p\leq q$, $p$ and $q$ primes, this shows that

$$G(2n)\sim \dfrac{Kn}{\log^{2} n}\prod_{p\vert n \\ p>2}\dfrac{p-1}{p-2}$$.

I have been told on a French maths forum that Hardy and Littlewood rigorously proved that if such a $K$ exists, then its value is such that their conjecture sometimes knowns as "extended Goldbach's conjecture" is true. Would you have a reference where this proof is given?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Section 4 of Hardy and Littlewood's "[On some problems of partitio numerorum III: On the expression of a number as a sum of primes](http://www.springerlink.com/content/d700t434065k0230/?MUD=MP)" 1923 Acta Math. 44: 1–70.

Comment: Thank you but I can't access.

Comment: Is there no library that would do an interlibrary loan for you?

Comment: Finally, I could get the whole article. Thank you again.

Comment: I removed the link given in the answer, as it (inadvertently I suppose) was the link through some proxy of some specific institution, which as such is useful for hardly anybody and might rather cause confusion.

Comment: That was indeed inadvertent. I replaced the link with a generic link to the Springerlink access point (paywalled).This, however, should work on many institutions networks.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF02403921](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02403921) ([JFM 48.0143.04](https://zbmath.org/48.0143.04)).