# If there are two primes at an even distance $k$ is there another disjoint pair of primes also at distance $k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Suppose $p,q$ are two primes at even distance $k$. Must there necessarily exist a different pair $p',q'$ composed of entirely different numbers such that $p'$ and $q'$ are also at distance $k$?

Edit: None of the primes need to be consecutive.

Comment: Your question sounds a bit unclear to me: do you require the two primes to be consecutive?

Comment: No, they don't need to be consecutive

Comment: This boils down to showing that any positive integer is a primality radius of at least two integers (see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture). I think there is some kind of duality between the number $N_{2}(n)$ of primality radii of n and the number $M_{r}(n)$ of integers $m$ below $n$ having a given positive integer $r$ as a primality radius. More precisely I expect the relation $N_{2}(n)\asymp_{r}M_{r}(n)$ to hold, but it remains highly conjectural.

Comment: I note for the OP's benefit that "primality radius" is not standard terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is conjectured that for *every* even number there are *infinitely* many pairs of primes at that distance.

Thus conjecturally the answer is: yes.

However, this is not known though there was huge progress around this problem recently by Zhang, Maynard and others.

The methods used to establish existence of primes at a certain distance is not typically helped by knowing one pair at that distance.

To wit, note that the Twin Prime conjecture, infinitely many primes at distance 2, is open, while obviously there is are instances of  pairs at this distance known. But this does not help much to get new ones.

It is an open problem if there is an even distance where there is exactly one pair of primes at that distance.  It seems extremely unlikely, but it cannot be at present excluded. So, what you ask is an open problem.

Comment: The question is perhaps poorly worded but as it stands now it only asks that: for every even $k$, there is not exactly one pair of primes at distance $k$ from each other. Though unusual, I find that question interesting too.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais It seems you mean to point out a discrepancy to what I wrote. Yet I do not see any. Could you please clarify the intent of the comment. First, I recalled a conjecture that would *imply* what is asked for. Then at the end I pick-up the question as aked, in the form of saying that the existence of a counterexample is open. At least doing this was the intent.

Comment: No, I was just happy you addressed that flimsy interpretation in your answer!

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Oh. That's great then! I should be more positive in my interpretations of comments. :-)