# Average value of $\prod_{p|d}{p-1\over p-2}$ for $d=nq$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$, with $p$ odd prime

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

$\newcommand{\mean}{\mathop{\mathrm{mean}}}$

Define
$$
S(d) = \prod_{p|d\atop p>2}{p-1\over p-2}.
$$
[Bombieri and Davenport](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2415368?read-now=1&seq=1) (1966) proved that
$$
\mean\limits_{d\in{\mathbb N}} S(d) = 
\mean\limits_{d\in{\mathbb N}} \prod_{p|d\atop p>2}{p-1\over p-2} ~=~ 
\Pi_2^{-1} = 1 / 0.66016\ldots = 1.51478\ldots\,, \tag{1}
$$
where $\Pi_2=0.66016\ldots$ is the [twin prime constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimesConstant.html).

It is not difficult to check that the average value of $S(d)$ remains unchanged ($=\Pi_2^{-1}$) if $d$ runs through an arithmetic progression $d=qn$ with $q=2^k$; in particular the average of $S(d)$ is $\Pi_2^{-1}$ when $d$ runs through all positive even integers.

Some experimentation with PARI/GP leads me to the following

**Generalization of** $(1)$ for an arithmetic progression $d=nq$, $n\in{\mathbb N}$:
$$
\mean\limits_{d=nq\atop n\in{\mathbb N}} S(d) = 
\mean\limits_{d=nq\atop n\in{\mathbb N}} 
\prod_{p|d\atop p>2}{p-1\over p-2} ~=~ 
\Pi_2^{-1} \prod_{p|q\atop p>2}{p\over p-1}.  \tag{2}
$$

For example, if $q=5$, then average of $S(d)$ over the progression $d=5n$ is $$\mean\limits_{d=5n\atop n\in{\mathbb N}} S(d) = {5\over4}\Pi_2^{-1}.$$

Can anyone please point me to existing proofs of $(2)$?
An idea/sketch of a proof would also be greatly appreciated!

**Note:** Let $q'$ be the largest odd divisor of $q$, then the "extra factor" in $(2)$ is

$$\prod_{p|q\atop p>2}{p\over p-1} = \prod_{p|q'}{p\over p-1} = 
{q'\over\varphi(q')}.
$$
In particular, if $q$ itself is odd, then the "extra factor" is $q/\varphi(q)$, as was noted in comments.

Comment: Note that the extra factor equals $q/\varphi(q)$.

Comment: You may also find https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture insightful.

Comment: $(1)$ follows from the same Tauberian theorem as in the proof of the PNT. Then for $(2)$ use that $S(nq)= S(q/\gcd(n,q))S(n)$

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, for *odd* $q$ the extra factor is $q/\varphi(q)$. For even $q$, it's slightly less pretty.

Comment: Thanks a lot @reuns for your insight! Could you possibly expand your comment into an answer, especially the $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ part, so I can upvote... :)  It looks less and less likely that someone comes up with a reference for proof of $(2)$...