# Is Fürstenberg's topology useful?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology, prime-numbers

It's hard not to be amused and perhaps even amazed when first encountering Fürstenberg's clever "topological" [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) that there are infinitely many primes. Closer inspection, however, reveals the disappointing truth that there really isn't anything topological going on there, as pointed out by BCnrd in a comment to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts/42517#42517).

Nevertheless, the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ introduced in the proof, where an open set is defined as any union of arithmetic sequences, does seem both natural and interesting.

My question is this: Can anything useful be done with this topology? Useful would include a new theorem, a simplification to a proof of a known result, or even fresh insight into standard material.

Comment: For the particular topology on the integers, it seems unlikely, especially as most (non-topological) results about the integers assume little or nothing about that topology.  I can imagine that an infinite product or some topological modification (something other than compactification) might produce interesting results.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.10.17

Comment: As BCnrd pointed out in his comments to another MO question, the topology is the one inherited from $\hat{\mathbf Z}$.  

Comment: Here is a version of Fuerstenberg's proof that does not mention topology: We argue about periodic subsets of $\mathbb Z$. The set of all numbers prime to a given $p$ is periodic and the intersection of two periodic sets is periodic. If there were only finitely many primes the set $\{-1,1\}$ would be periodic.

Comment: A standard and more accurate name is "profinite topology".

Answer (score 19):

The answer to your question is yes, but it is a stretch to claim that the topology is due to Furstenberg.  There is an extended discussion on Furstenberg's proof in the comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34699/approaches-to-riemann-hypothesis-using-methods-outside-number-theory/34718#34718).  The short version is as Chandan Singh Dalawat said in the comments above: this topology on the integers is the profinite topology, and people had been studying profinite topologies long before Furstenberg.

The topology is useful in the sense that profinite completions are useful.  In particular, you may argue that it is a natural topology on the fundamental group of a circle (or the punctured complex affine line), since its profinite completion is the geometric fundamental group of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$.  It also appears in some form whenever one uses the ring of adeles $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}$, which you may encounter when studying Tate's thesis or automorphic representations.

Comment: Since Prüfer,  *Neue Begründung der algebraischen Zahlentheorie*, Math. Annalen **94** (1925), 198-243 (http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0094).

Answer (score 7):

A more rigorous version of Scott's answer:  If a topology on a group $G$ is translation-invariant, then it also defines a *uniformity* on $G$, by definition a distinguished set of neighborhoods of the diagonal $G \times G$ that is analogous to a metric.  Actually, in the present example with $G = \mathbb{Z}$, the uniformity comes from a metric.  Like the metric spaces that they generalize, uniform spaces have completions.  The completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the uniformity cited by Furstenberg is exactly the adelic profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Or if $G$ is any group, there is a similar topology generated by finite-index subgroups, and a uniformity, and the completion is the profinite completion.

Comment: For $G$ to *embed* into its profinite completion $\hat G$, it should be *residually finite* (for every $x\in G$, there should be a finite quotient $H_x$ of $G$ in which the image of $x$ is $\neq1$).

Comment: That's true.  If $X$ is a uniform space, then it does not necessarily embed into its completion either; rather it has a canonical Hausdorff quotient which embeds.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "For every $x\neq1$ in $G$" instead of "For every $x\in G$". But this lapse doesn't seem to have led to any confusion !