# Topology and infinite number of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology

One of the strange proofs (among the other beautiful proof) in the book *"Proofs from the book"* is the fifth one, which uses a special topology on the set of integer numbers, to prove there are infinite prime numbers.

My question is:

Is this method special just for this case, or is there anything deeper and this technique (or its generalization) can be used for some other kinds of problems?

A related question (by @ToddTrimble comment):

[Is Fürstenberg's topology useful?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42589/is-f%C3%BCrstenbergs-topology-useful)

Comment: When unwound straightforwardly, the "topological" proof is really just the usual proof in disguise (and it doesn't use anything more than the *language* of topology in the first place). That said, I am under the impression that the topology introduced there is actually interesting, just not really for that reason.

Comment: If anybody could mention which topology it is, it would help answering the question. (If it's the profinite one, it definitely has a huge number of uses, say $p$-adic numbers and so on.)

Comment: Certainly it's the profinite topology, i.e., the topology inherited from the profinite completion $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ that appears in the adeles, as pointed out by Chandan Singh Dalawat here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/42589/2926

Comment: @Todd Trimble It seems that I must delete this question, yes?

Comment: It's your call. I'm not suggesting you should. Maybe someone would like to say something even more enlightening than the hints given so far in comments; dunno.

Comment: It is generous!

Comment: PS the "Furstenberg topology" is the terminology given by some subcommunity to the profinite topology.

Comment: There is a modfication of the Furstenberg topology, called the Golomb topology (see e.g https://mathoverflow.net/q/285557). It is generated by the base consisting of the arithmetic progressions $\mathbb N\cap(a+b\mathbb Z)$ with coprime $a,b$. By the famous Dirichlet Theorem, the set of prime numbers is dense in the Golomb topology (but not in the Furstenberg one). Golomb popularized this topology expecting to find a topological proof of the famous Dirichet Theorem on density of primes. But till now  such a topological proof has not been found.

Comment: @Taras I am aware of Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, but that's not a density result. What density result do you have in mind, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had in mind the density in topological sense (as the density of the set of primes in the Golomb topology).